# XPS15 9570 + Thunderbolt 3 ethernet constantly dropping out

Tags: networking, drivers, ethernet, 20.10, thunderbolt

I have an XPS 9570 running Ubtuntu 20.10 and an Elgato Thunderbolt 3 mini dock. All the ports are working, but the ethernet is really unstable. It works for about 2 seconds and afterwards it drops out for a second and comes back again.
I already set the thunderbolt 3 mode to no security which fixed the usb output.
I have disabled TLP and plugged the laptop into AC. This didn't fix it either.
When booted into Windows, there is no problem with stability.

In the output of dmesg you can clearly see the connection going up and down when the cable is plugged in.

```
[ 1008.264943] tg3 0000:07:00.0 ens1: Link is down
[ 1011.307241] tg3 0000:07:00.0 ens1: Link is up at 1000 Mbps, full duplex
[ 1011.307246] tg3 0000:07:00.0 ens1: Flow control is on for TX and on for RX
[ 1011.307249] tg3 0000:07:00.0 ens1: EEE is enabled
[ 1013.625053] tg3 0000:07:00.0 ens1: Link is down
[ 1016.636342] tg3 0000:07:00.0 ens1: Link is up at 1000 Mbps, full duplex
[ 1016.636347] tg3 0000:07:00.0 ens1: Flow control is on for TX and on for RX
[ 1016.636350] tg3 0000:07:00.0 ens1: EEE is enabled
[ 1019.877241] tg3 0000:07:00.0 ens1: Link is down
[ 1022.843123] tg3 0000:07:00.0 ens1: Link is up at 1000 Mbps, full duplex
[ 1022.843128] tg3 0000:07:00.0 ens1: Flow control is on for TX and on for RX
[ 1022.843130] tg3 0000:07:00.0 ens1: EEE is enabled
[ 1052.584320] tg3 0000:07:00.0 ens1: Link is down
[ 1055.499589] tg3 0000:07:00.0 ens1: Link is up at 1000 Mbps, full duplex
[ 1055.499617] tg3 0000:07:00.0 ens1: Flow control is on for TX and on for RX
[ 1055.499635] tg3 0000:07:00.0 ens1: EEE is enabled
[ 1058.704318] tg3 0000:07:00.0 ens1: Link is down
[ 1061.641735] tg3 0000:07:00.0 ens1: Link is up at 1000 Mbps, full duplex
[ 1061.641764] tg3 0000:07:00.0 ens1: Flow control is on for TX and on for RX
[ 1061.641769] tg3 0000:07:00.0 ens1: EEE is enabled
[ 1064.767652] tg3 0000:07:00.0 ens1: Link is down
[ 1067.759536] tg3 0000:07:00.0 ens1: Link is up at 1000 Mbps, full duplex
[ 1067.759565] tg3 0000:07:00.0 ens1: Flow control is on for TX and on for RX
[ 1067.759570] tg3 0000:07:00.0 ens1: EEE is enabled
[ 1071.026376] tg3 0000:07:00.0 ens1: Link is down
[ 1073.972821] tg3 0000:07:00.0 ens1: Link is up at 1000 Mbps, full duplex
[ 1073.972849] tg3 0000:07:00.0 ens1: Flow control is on for TX and on for RX
[ 1073.972854] tg3 0000:07:00.0 ens1: EEE is enabled
[ 1077.708775] tg3 0000:07:00.0 ens1: Link is down
[ 1080.741436] tg3 0000:07:00.0 ens1: Link is up at 1000 Mbps, full duplex
[ 1080.741462] tg3 0000:07:00.0 ens1: Flow control is on for TX and on for RX
[ 1080.741467] tg3 0000:07:00.0 ens1: EEE is enabled
[ 1086.415177] tg3 0000:07:00.0 ens1: Link is down
[ 1089.617665] tg3 0000:07:00.0 ens1: Link is up at 1000 Mbps, full duplex
[ 1089.617666] tg3 0000:07:00.0 ens1: Flow control is on for TX and on for RX
[ 1089.617667] tg3 0000:07:00.0 ens1: EEE is enabled
[ 1099.637822] tg3 0000:07:00.0 ens1: Link is down
```

Any ideas what causes this behavior?

Comment: Maybe this is the issue? Should I disable EEE?
Press in the IEEE 802.3az EEE ON/OFF button on the front panel to turn on the EEE feature. Disable it if you don't want the network performance to be impacted due to the latency from the additional time required for the sleep and wake transition or if the remote side doesn't support it.

Comment: @David it was indeed the Energy-Efficient Ethernet (EEE) which caused the dropouts. After disabling it using `ethtool --set-eee ens1 eee off` the connection was rock solid.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Disable EEE it if you don't want the network performance to be impacted due to the latency from the additional time required for the sleep and wake transition or if the remote side doesn't support it.

Answer (score 0):

As @David pointed out it was Energy-Efficient Ethernet (EEE) that was causing the dropouts. After using `ethtool --set-eee ens1 eee off` found [here](https://www.toradex.com/community/questions/14403/how-to-disable-energy-efficient-ethernet.html) the connection doesn't drop anymore.

You should add `igb.EEE=0` to kernel cmdline to disable EEE during boot, otherwise you have to use the command every reboot.