# Wifi latency spikes on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, 20.04, iwlwifi

I used to have wifi latency between an Asus router and a Dell XPS 15 (7590) laptop around 1 ms. Then something happened (probably an update) and now the latency jumps to 30 ms - 110 ms for a few seconds several times per minute.

The problem isn't very noticeable when not gaming or doing something that requires multiple roundtrips before changing something onscreen, so I am not sure when did it exactly start. I have probably updated the system during this time. It came at a similar time than a possibly unrelated problem causing the sound to get progressively more noisy and distorted until I restart pulseaudio or suspend the laptop. I rebooted the system only when the problems became too annoying (hoping they would disappear), so a firmware update is probably not the problem.

The problem does not happen on different machines running Windows or Mac OS connected to the same wifi network. It also doesn't happen if I connect to the router via a cable (via a Thunderbolt dock, the laptop has no ethernet connector). This makes me blame wireless specifically.

It does not happen on the wireless network's properties. It happens for both 2.4 GHz wifi a 5 GHz wifi, for WPA2 encrypted wifi and open wifi.

The wifi device is recognised as `Wi-Fi 6 AX200` from Intel when I use `lspci`, but `dmesg` has a message it was identified as `Killer(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX1650x 160MHz Wireless Network Adapter (200NGW), REV=0x340` (which is correct). The driver seems to be `iwlwifi`. It used to work out of the box until recently.

The log messages in `dmesg` that pertain to `iwl` contain little information, only this if I get it to restart:

```
[156207.972224] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[156208.144594] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
```

I have found [somebody may have a similar problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1315065/trying-to-eliminate-latency-spikes-on-ubuntu-20-04), but the question was not answered for weeks and contains very little information.

I tried reinstalling the driver, changing power saving settings, but it didn't help. It happens if CPU is almost unused.

Any idea what could be broken?

More information based on questions in comments:

- Command `ip link show` shows `<BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000` for the wifi I am connected to. MTU is probably good enough.

Comment: Take a look at this it may help. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1320233/xps15-9570-thunderbolt-3-ethernet-constantly-dropping-out/1320242#1320242

Comment: That's a completely different issue. It was tracked to an ethernet-specific problem, while in my case, ethernet works fine and wifi is weird. I did suspect power management, but disabling it didn't seem to help.

Comment: Do `ip link show`. What is your WiFi MTU?

Comment: It says `<BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000` for my wifi, so my MTU is probably 1500. I don't know what is a good value.

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story.

Comment: Okay, I added it to the quesiton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have assumed it was a regression in some wifi-related program and upgraded to Ubuntu 20.10. The problem is now gone, the wifi latency is stable.